# what is the best way to read a large xml file in a singleton class

Tags: java, design-patterns, constructor, singleton

I have a singleton class which read some properties from a xml file which has quite a huge number of elements.Currently, I am reading the xml file inside the constructor of the singleton class. once the entries in the xml is read, I can access those from the singleton instance without having to read the xml again and again. I would like to know if this is a correct approach or is there better way to get it done than this.

Comment: As long as your XML is read before the singleton instance is returned to calling code, where exactly  you do this (constructor, static initializer, private init method) does not matter much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to lazily load the properties, then you can write the class as below, It will work in multi-threaded environment as well.

```
class Singleton {
    private static Singleton instance;
    private Properties xmlProperties;

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(Singleton.class) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public Properties getXmlProperties() {
        if(xmlProperties == null) {
            initProperties();
        }
        return xmlProperties;
    }

    private synchronized void initProperties() {
        if(xmlProperties == null) {
            //Initialize the properties from Xml properties file
            // xmlProperties = (Properties from XML file)
        }
    }
}
```